# Issue with title tag in <img> - show text until spacebar

Tags: html, internationalization, coffeescript

So I have little issue with my title tag.

So I have some message like

```
IHaveSpacebars = I'd like to show you everything
```

I'm adding image via coffescript because I have to, but I think it wouldn't change a thing, so heres image code

```
<img src=\"#{url("/static/css/images/tick_shield.png")}\" style=\"margin-top:-6px\" title=" + i18n('IHaveSpacebars') + ">
```

i18n returns full string "I'd like to show you everything" so this is working well (checked via firebug).
So my issue: when I move mouse cursor over my image tick_shield.png it shows only **I'd** instead of **I'd like to show you everything**. I believe I messed up with this " + variable + " in title tag but I couldn't find anything else :/ **examples that don't work:**

```
title=i18n('IHaveSpacebars')
```

returns i18n('IHaveSpacebars') instead of txt

```
IHaveSpacebars = "I'd like to show you everything"
```

giving that one " " works, but that string is also used in other names (like column name) which will return column name with " ".

So do you guys (and girls:)) know how to write it correctly? I'm sure it's my fault with this " + . + " but couldn't find how to write it different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out a solution so maybe someone will find it helpful:

```
title="+"'"+i18n('IHaveSpacebars')+"'
```

The reason why it didn't work was that my original code `title="+i18n('IHaveSpacebars')+"` was returning

```
<img src="" title='I'd' like to show you everything>
```

while code above is returning

```
<img src="" title='I'd like to show you everything'>
```

Cheers ;)